# NavigationIcon click not working in ActionBar

Tags: android

In my actvity, I created a ActionBar, used a back icon, its showing in the app, but on clicking back icon nothing is happening, didn't got the function onnavigationiconclick event working also, below is my code, kindly assist so that on clicking the back icon user can be send to MainActivity --

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab1gridlatestvideos);

        ActionBar actionBar=getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayOptions(actionBar.getDisplayOptions()
                | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);

        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle("Latest Videos");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Inside your activity**

`getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`
   `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);`

```
@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
 onBackPressed();
 return true;
}
```

Comment: not working bro

Comment: @Dinesh try this one

Comment: done bro. thnx a lot

Comment: @DineshKumar not mention bro

Answer (score 0):

In the manifest xml, set this attribute for the activity from where you want to navigate up:

`android:parentActivityName="com.example.MainActivity"`

Set the value to the activity you want to navigate back to.

Add this `meta data` tag for supporting android versions 4.0 or lower:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
```

For information at: [Providing Up Navigation](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html)

Note: Since you have used `ActionBar` object, make sure you are using the right one, that is `android.support.v7.app.ActionBar`

Answer (score 0):

**try using a custom toolbar in activity.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

**1- set your toolbar**

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
```

**2- setup your icon**

```
if (toolbar != null) {
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

}
```

**3- override this method**

```
@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    onBackPressed();
    return true;
}
```